# Library in Ubuntu to get the name of current windows open similar to win32gui

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, win32gui

Is there any library in Ubuntu to know the names of current windows open, similar to win32gui in Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wmctrl -l` should do the job
    [wmctrl manual](http://tripie.sweb.cz/utils/wmctrl/#help)